# How to Convert ULONGLONG to CString

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm using vs-2013 for MFC application Development & my MFC project's character set is **multi-byte character set**
I want to know How do I convert **ULONGLONG** data-type to **CString** in my MFC Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
ULONGLONG t = 238979237947;
CString S;
//S.Format(L"blah blah : %I64u", t);  // For Unicode
S.Format("blah blah : %I64u", t);     // For Multi-byte
MessageBox(S);
```

Comment: And remember you can always google search "convert ULONGLONG Cstring" :)

Comment: ps. Remove 'L' to suit asker's Multibyte comment